# storing multiple user session values in a session log file

Tags: php, session

I try to store more than one session value in a file of SESSION directory, but when i tried to store a new value it overwrites the old value and stores only the new value.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Simple HTML Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $_SESSION['userName'] = 'nancy';
    $_SESSION['emailAddress'] = 'nancy@gmail.com';
    $_SESSION['userName'] = 'preeti';
    $_SESSION['emailAddress'] = 'preeti@gmail.com';

    $session_data = session_encode(); // Get the session data
    // change the name below for the folder you want
 $dir = "SESSION";
$file_to_write = 'session_log';
$content_to_write = " $session_data";
if( is_dir($dir) === false )
{
    mkdir($dir);
}
$file = fopen($dir . '/' . $file_to_write,"w");
// a different way to write content into
// fwrite($file,"Hello World.");
fwrite($file, $content_to_write);
// closes the file
fclose($file);
// this will show the created file from the created folder on screen
include $dir . '/' . $file_to_write;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

what should i do

Comment: I think you have to append the data, every time you are open the file in read mode and override the existing data, instead of it you have append the data on file

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of users and append the data to it:

```
$_SESSION['users'] = array();

$_SESSION['users'][] = array(
    'name' => 'nancy',
    'email' => 'nancy@gmail.com',
);

$_SESSION['users'][] = array(
    'name' => 'preeti',
    'email' => 'preeti@gmail.com',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add values in session array so your values not overide like this
```

declare a array
   $_SESSION['info'] = array();

```
$_SESSION['info'][] = array(
    'fullname' => 'manish',
   'email' => 'nancy@gmail.com',
);


$_SESSION['info'][] = array(
    'fullname' => 'manish1',
   'email' => 'nancy@gmail1.com',
);
```